# Vertex Cover without covering all edges

Tags: graphs, terminology

What would be the name of the problem of a vertex cover that covers all the vertices without the requirement of covering all the edges?

Vertex cover has to answer whether or not there is a set of $k$ vertices that covers all the edges of the graph, covering therefore, all the vertices. What is the name of the problem that, similarly to vertex cover, select a subset of $k$ vertices that has direct edges to all the vertices, but without necessarily covering all the edges of the graph?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your description correctly, you are looking for a [dominating set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominating_set).